# Why is the 23rd translated as the 22nd day of the month?

Tags: traducción

In "*The Outcasts of Poker Flat*" by Bret Harte, it says:

**...on the morning of the twenty-third of November, ...**

The Spanish translation ("Los Desterrados de Poker Flat") has it thus:

**...en la mañana del dia 22 de noviembre...**

Is this right? Is the 23rd considered the 22nd among Spanish speakers, or is this a mis-translation/typo?

Comment: Obviusly, it is a typo.

Comment: I tend to agree, but the fact that "once a week" is "cada ocho dias" makes me wonder...

Comment: In spain we hate the number 23

Comment: kpax, so you hate Michael Jordan?!? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it *has* to be a typo. The 22nd was Friday, both in English and Spanish; and that would not match well with feeling "a Sabbath lull in the air" that morning.