# Why is "Dawn" translated "Mediodía"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

Me parece que "mediodía" significa "noon" y "dawn" debe ser "amanecer," pero:

In "*The Outcasts of Poker Flat / Los Desterrados de Poker Flat*" (por Bret Harte) the original English has this:

> "...waited for the **dawn**."

Whereas the Spanish translation puts it this way:

> "...esperó la luz del **mediodía**,..."

Why would dawn be translated "mediodía" instead of "amanecer" here? It makes no sense, at any rate - the protagonist has been sleeping; it would naturally be the dawn he awaits, not noon.

Is there any possible sensible reason why "dawn" would be translated "mediodía" here?

Comment: A bad translator, that's all I can think of.  Like you said, `dawn` is not `noon`.

Comment: I've always been under the impression that "dawn" is translated to "madrugada".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, `dawn` should be translated as "amanecer" or ["alba"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=albas)

> ... esperó al amanecer.
>
> ... esperó a las primeras luces del alba

Seeing that you [already found](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13325/5481) a really blatant example of bad translation in the version of that book you are working with, it should not be surprising this is another oner.

Comment: Yes, I've found a few, like "Kansas" being translated as "Arkansas", even though "Kansas" appears a couple of times more a page later. Also, where "mad" as in angry (obvious based on the context) is translated "loco."

Answer (score 1):

"Dawn" should be translated as "amanecer" or "alba" (less used), but not as "mediodía". It may refer to different hours depending of the country. The literal meaning is "half a day" or "the middle of a day" (12 a.m.) but in many countries we use it to talk about the hour when we have lunch (in Spain 2 or 3 p.m.).